# add function output directly at the end of a matrix

Tags: matlab

i have a cell that contains several n by 3 matrices. Now i want the output of a function, which is two times a 1 by 3 matrix to be the last entry on two of matrices from the cell.
I have it done like this now, which works. But i was wondering if it is also possible to do it in one line?

```
 [a] = functionfile(function_input)
 b{x1}(n,:) = a{1};
 b{x2}(n,:) = a{2};
```

So in this case a results in a{1} and a{2} both being a 1 by 3 matrix with scalars. And b is a cell with many n by 3 matrices, but only on two of those matrices the nth row has to be replaced. Namely from x1 and x2. 
So the code above first stores it in a new variable a and then overwrites the last row in b. But if i use it directly, like:

```
  [b{x1}(n,:)  b{x2}(n,:)] = functionfile(function_input)
```

I get the error:

> Error using functionfile 
>   Too many output arguments.

And that is because in the function file itself, the output is written as

```
  [a] = functionfile(function_input)
```

but if i replace it with

```
  [a{1} a{2}] = functionfile(function_input)
```

it will give me

> Error: File: functionfile.m Line: 1 Column: 13 Unbalanced or
>   unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

When a{1} and a{2} are the only parts that exist in a, a{3}, a{4} and such do never exist.
The only solution i could think of was to write a{1} and a{2} as two different variables within the function file. However then i can no longer use the for loop which will mess it up there.

Comment: Shouldn't the output of your function be `b`, not `a`?  Only two entries in `b` need to be replaced, right?

Comment: but contains many matrices that are n by 3.
while a is only two matrices of 1 by 3. this a only become a very small portion of b.

Comment: So you want to return `a` which is just two of the 1 x 3 arrays from `b`? You're not making it very clear.

Comment: I was only wondering if it is possible to use the first 3 lines of code together in one line of code without using the extra temporarily variable a.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't.  No assignment operations can happen in return arguments in a function.  You need to explicitly assign them in the main body of your function before returning them.  You don't have a way around it.... but why do you want to do it in one line?  You gain very little efficiency if I understand what you want correctly.